# param is missing or the value is empty error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble with the params.require().permit(). I have a User model from devise and a group model which represents a class (as in an academic class). When the user is on the groups index view I want them to be able to click join and become part of that group.

```
<%= form_for @student, :url => students_path(@student), method: :post do %>
    <%= hidden_field :student_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= hidden_field :course_id, :value => group.id %>
    <%= submit_tag "+ Join", :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right join-button" %>
<% end %>
```

My thinking was I would pass the current users id as well as the group ID that they click join for as hidden values so there would just be a join button.

My group controllers index method looks like this

```
def index
    @groups = Group.all
    @student = Student.new
end
```

My Student Controller looks like this:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_student, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    #@students = Student.all
    @students = Student.where(:student_id => current_user.id)
    #respond_with(@students)
  end

  def show
    #respond_with(@student)
    @students = Student.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @student = Student.new
    #respond_with(@student)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)
    @student.save
    #respond_with(@student)
  end

  def update
    @student.update(student_params)
    #respond_with(@student)
  end

  def destroy
    @student.destroy
    #respond_with(@student)
  end

  private
    def set_student
      @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    end

    def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(:course_id, :student_id)
    end
end
```

Whenever I try and submit the form (aka click the join button) I get an error saying:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: student
```

I also get this info which is correct as far as the student and group ID's

```
Request

Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"/bJYZBGr6lfAzb9mYnvRfMZII+QS8iskd0MRuHh+RnE=",
 "course_id"=>"10",
 "student_id"=>"4"}
```

This also does insert into the database, but the student_id and course_id are nil. I am guessing this has something to do with strong params but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: which action it is redirecting when you click on `join` button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your form_builder object is missing from the form_for block. Try this:

```
<%= form_for @student, :url => students_path(@student), method: :post do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :student_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :course_id, :value => group.id %>
<%= submit_tag "+ Join", :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right join-button" %>
<% end %>
```

without the builder I don't believe rails will provide a student hash in the submitted params

Comment: Wow! I am surprised at how it was such a simple answer. Thank you so much for your help! It is working great now!

Comment: Your form is the same as ajs4550's form. Where is difference ?

Comment: @parzival  notice that the the op's form does pass the block variable |f| and the lines that the declare the form fields are not prefixed with f.[field_name]

Answer (score 1):

in the before _action   set_student
you are usin param[:id] , while your params don't have it .. I think you should use param[:student_id] instead

Comment: I am sorry, can you clarify a bit more. I don't see where in the before_action set_student I am using param[:id].

Comment: Ok, I actually see what youre saying now. I think it is correct though because student will have the param ID because its more of a relational database tying a user with a course

Comment: the student in the DB will have the id .. but you are passing it in the request with name " student_id "

so it should be ...
 def set_student
      @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
 end

 ... find onle without   fint_by_...  will find by id

Comment: Well when you visit the group index page there is no student yet. I do Student.new which I would assume would make a new student and set an ID for it but doesn't it not know about the student_id yet since I did not click join?

Comment: you make before action works only with  [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

it won't work with index action .. as you mention that .. and even in the index action .. do you pass param[:id] with is in the get request ?

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. So I want to create a new relationship between a user and a group, that new relationship is called a student. I can't pass the student ID because it doesn't exist until the user clicks the join button and the relationship is created. In the group controller I do call @student = Student.new so shouldn't I be able to pass the id from the student DB with a hidden field and something along the lines of @student.id? Or would that not work? I don't believe the student has an ID when you're on the group index even though I call Student.new

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing @student isn't the path just student_path(@student) rather than what you had, which is students_path(@student)?

Comment: When I do that and go to localhost:3000/groups I get this error. "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"students", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]"